# How we use the convexity to prove that the limit is $0$? (In Orlicz space)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, orlicz-spaces

Hello please i have that $w_{\rho}(x)=h_{\rho}(x)w(x)$ where

$$w\in L^{\Phi}(\mathbb{R}^N)=\{u\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N); \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\Phi(\frac{|u|}{\lambda})dx<+\infty~\text{for some}~\lambda>0\}$$

and $h_{\rho}\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N,[0,1])$ such that $h_{\rho}(x)\equiv 1~\text{on}~B_{\rho}(0),~\text{and}~ supp(h_{\rho})\subset B_{2\rho}(0)$

How to prove that 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\Phi(|w_{\rho_n}(x)-w(x)|)dx
\overset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0
$$

$(\rho_n)$ is a real sequence where $\rho_n\rightarrow +\infty,~\text{whene}~ n\rightarrow+\infty$

where $\Phi$ is a real positive convex function

Answer (score 3):

The convex image of an integrable function need not be integrable. As an example of this, let $\sqrt 2< a< 2$ and consider $w:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ given by 
\begin{equation*}
w(x) = 
\begin{cases}
a^j & \text{ if } 2j - 1< x< 2j-1+2^{1- j}\\
0 & \text{ otherwise}, 
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
where $j= 1, 2, \ldots$. Let $\Phi(r) = r^2$. On one hand, since $a< 2$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb R} w(x)\; dx = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty a^j 2^{1-j}< \infty. 
\end{equation*}
On the other hand, since $a>\sqrt 2$ we have 
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb R} \Phi(w(x))\; dx = \int_{\mathbb R} w^2(x)\; dx = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty a^{2j}2^{1 - j} = +\infty. 
\end{equation*}

Comment: It seems that @supinf has provided a much simpler example illustrating that the convex image of an integrable function need not be integrable.

Comment: see my edit please

Comment: please delete your answer it is false

Comment: @Vrouvrou: why do you downvote this answer? sorry but your comment is rude but also factually wrong. Moreover, you have not explained why BindersFull is wrong as you claim

Comment: A less explicit example with the same message: If $w > 0$ is your favourite positive function in $L^1 \setminus L^p$, $p>1$ and $\Phi(r ) = r^p$ then $∫ w = ‖w‖_1$ and $∫ \Phi(w) = ‖w‖_p^p = ∞$

Answer (score 1):

the statement is wrong.

Consider the constant function $\Phi=1$ which is convex. Then the integral
$$
 \int_{\mathbb R^n} 1 \,\mathrm dx = \infty
$$
 and thus does not converge to $0$.

Edit: OP made same changes to the question and added non-obvious assumptions, but i am leaving my original answer up here.

Comment: why it is $\infty$ ? it is impossible ,

Comment: i have edited to clarify. Note that the domain is infinite

Comment: from where we can have that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}$ see that $supp(h)\subset B_{2\rho}(0)$

Comment: see the edit please

Comment: please delete your answer it is fals

Comment: @Vrouvrou you might do yourself some good to explain why it is "false". (hint: it isn't)

Comment: see the space where $w$ is  and why you delete $h$ have you understand the question ?